# how to make display like sales order lines in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am a newbie in odoo development, can someone tell me how to make display like in picture [sales order line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3Q1D.png) in odoo, Thank you before

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your attempt so far. This website is about helping people with specific problems, not doing their work for them. If you can show you've made some effort you're more likely to get help.

Comment: You better check the [official doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/).

Comment: No need to put image into separate url.You insert it in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is One2many field in Odoo
to made one like this you have to add some things like this:

In python code

```
from openerp import fields,models
class sale_order(models.Model):
     _inherit='sale.order'
     field_One2many=field.One2many('sale.order.line','order_id','Order')
sale_order()
class sale_order_line(models.model):
     _inherit='sale.order.line'
     order_id=fields.Many2one('sale.order','Order')
sale_order_line()
```

and you have some code for the view in your Xml file like:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_test">
            <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale_order.form_view_id"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data>
                    <xpath expr="pass of position" position="the postion">
                        <field name='field_One2many'>
                          <tree>
                             <!-- Your Fields in the view -->
                          </tree>
                      </field>
                    </xpath>
                </data>
            </field>
        </record>
```

and done